# How to check if a contact retrieved from the address book doesn't have phone number?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

I get contacts from the address book in my app, but when I take out a contact that doesn't have a number I get an exception. What should I do? How to check contact number for nil?!
How to check if a contact retrieved from the address book doesn't have phone number?

```
ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    if (ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0)) {
        NSLog(@"No number available");
        cont.number=@"No number available";
    }
    else {
    cont.number = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is originally from [iPhoneDevSDK](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1503-retrieving-phone-number-address-book.html). I've modified it some:

```
ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(
    person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

CFIndex numPhoneNums = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones);
if(numPhoneNums == 0) {
    NSLog(@"No number available");
    cont.number = @"No number available";
} else {
    cont.number = (NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, 0);
}
```

Note this will give you the first phone number, if it exists. If you want to get for a particular label then you need to loop through, testing on `ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i)` until you find the label you want.

Comment: THe number isn't retrieved at all

Comment: try removing (NSString *) typecasting for "phones".